# From which directory can I start mysql on linux

Tags: mysql, linux

Which unix directory should I navigate to before I can issue:
service mysql start

Can I do it from any directory? I don't have a  'mysql' folder under /var/lib

Answer (score 2):

Technically you could do it from anywhere. You're actually calling `service` first, which is available anywhere. The important thing is that you must have `mysql` installed, or else it won't find the service that you want to start

Answer (score 0):

Your daemon had to be in the /etc/init.d directory

Comment: fyi...CentOS07 is doing away with init scripts...you will need to start service for mysql on regular install of CentOS07